# Calender on Android App

Tags: android, user-interface, calendar

I'm still learning how to build an android app,but I really could use a help in this part of an app.

I have to build an calendar with an events options.
The first activity must show the month and the days of these month,and must allow the person to navigate to other months and years.
Also must be possible to click on the date and open another activity with a list of events,and in this screen must be possible to click on the event to see it details.
And,of course,the user has to be able to add events.

The event has basic informations(name,description,date and a class related to it).

I believe there is a calender provider,but I don't know yet how to use.

So,does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Caldroid for showing and customizing the calendar. The API is provided with great explanation related to its usage.

Below is the link for the same:

[Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

For Calendar you can use the above and for rest functionality manage your code with your logics.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is, create an app to set events in system calendar. you can refer android developer site to understand system calendar.
1) [Link 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)
2) [Link2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

Another way is to use pre build calendar interface (like outlook calendar). In our productions we use dhtmlx scheduler. Then you need to build whole application with more complex logic.